# Vue 3 & Apollo Composable - Are we obliged to call useMutation and useQuery inside setup()

Tags: graphql, vuejs3, vue-apollo

I am new in Vue 3 and Apollo Composable. I first created a Vuex store and a module service to fetch data from GraphQL endpoint. Furthermore, I noticed during implementation that I can't call useMutation and useQuery outside of setup().

Can I have more explanations about that and also if there are other ways to use useQuery and useMutation outside of setup() can you please show them to me ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can use provideApolloClient to get access of it outside of a component. You can do it like this:

```
import { provideApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { defaultClient } from '../../vue-apollo';
import { useQuery, useResult, useLazyQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

provideApolloClient(defaultClient)
```

The import of defaultClient from vue-apollo file is my own file, were I have defined HttpLink and ApolloClient that uses that HttpLink. Feel free to ping me, if you need clarification.

Comment: Why are you importing from another file. The default client should be accessible from Vue instance right ?

Comment: useQuery works this way but useMutation does not. There is different solution where i can use mutation outside of setup() vue component?

Comment: @LukasGur They have fixed it now with vue-apollo v4 alpha 16: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/issues/1262

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks buddies